Ошибка при установки Redmine
Хотел установить Redmine на свой сервер. Сталкиваюсь с такой ошибкой:
Could not find rake-13.2.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

  /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:86:in `block in materialize'
  /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:80:in `map!'
  /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:80:in `materialize'
  /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
  /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
  /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
  /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:101:in `block in definition_method'
  /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
  /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:149:in `setup'
  /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:136:in `with_level'
  /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:88:in `silence'
  /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:430:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:297:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:435:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:296:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'

Выше подсказка, что нужно ввести команду bundle install - сделал, ошибка осталось такой же.
Прошу помочь, кто знает, что с этим делать.
Содержимое Gamefile:

ruby '>= 2.5.0', '< 3.2.0'
gem 'bundler', '>= 1.12.0'

gem 'rake', '13.2.1'
gem 'rails', '6.1.7.8'
gem 'globalid', '~> 0.4.2' if Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.6.0')
gem 'rouge', '~> 3.28.0'
gem 'request_store', '~> 1.5.0'
gem 'mini_mime', '~> 1.1.0'
gem "actionpack-xml_parser"
gem 'roadie-rails', (Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.6.0') ? '~> 2.2.0' : '~> 3.0.0')
gem 'marcel'
gem "mail", "~> 2.7.1"
gem 'csv', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'nokogiri', (if Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.6.0')
                   '~> 1.12.5'
                 elsif Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.7.0')
                   '~> 1.13.10'
                 else
                   '~> 1.15.2'
                 end)
gem "rexml", require: false if Gem.ruby_version >= Gem::Version.new('3.0')
gem 'i18n', '~> 1.10.0'
gem 'rbpdf', '~> 1.21.3'
gem 'addressable'
gem 'rubyzip', '~> 2.3.0'
gem 'net-smtp', '~> 0.3.0'
gem 'net-imap', '~> 0.2.2'
gem 'net-pop', '~> 0.1.1'
# Rails 6.1.6.1 does not work with Pysch 3.0.2, which is installed by default with Ruby 2.5. See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/45590
gem 'psych', '>= 3.1.0' if Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.6.0')

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin]

# TOTP-based 2-factor authentication
gem 'rotp', '>= 5.0.0'
gem 'rqrcode'

# Optional gem for LDAP authentication
group :ldap do
  gem 'net-ldap', '~> 0.17.0'
end

# Optional gem for exporting the gantt to a PNG file
group :minimagick do
  gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.11.0'
end

# Optional Markdown support, not for JRuby
# ToDo: Remove common_mark group when common_mark is decoupled from markdown. See defect (#36892) for more details.
gem 'redcarpet', '~> 3.5.1', groups: [:markdown, :common_mark]

# Optional CommonMark support, not for JRuby
group :common_mark do
  gem "html-pipeline", "~> 2.13.2"
  gem "commonmarker", (Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.6.0') ? '0.21.0' : '~> 0.23.8')
  gem "sanitize", "~> 6.0"
  gem 'deckar01-task_list', '2.3.2'
end

# Include database gems for the adapters found in the database
# configuration file
require 'erb'
require 'yaml'
database_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "config/database.yml")
if File.exist?(database_file)
  yaml_config = ERB.new(IO.read(database_file)).result
  database_config = YAML.respond_to?(:unsafe_load) ? YAML.unsafe_load(yaml_config) : YAML.load(yaml_config)
  adapters = database_config.values.map {|c| c['adapter']}.compact.uniq
  if adapters.any?
    adapters.each do |adapter|
      case adapter
      when 'mysql2'
        gem "mysql2", "~> 0.5.0", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
      when /postgresql/
        gem "pg", "~> 1.2.2", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
      when /sqlite3/
        gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.4.0", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
      when /sqlserver/
        gem "tiny_tds", "~> 2.1.2", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
        gem "activerecord-sqlserver-adapter", "~> 6.1.0", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
      else
        warn("Unknown database adapter `#{adapter}` found in config/database.yml, use Gemfile.local to load your own database gems")
      end
    end
  else
    warn("No adapter found in config/database.yml, please configure it first")
  end
else
  warn("Please configure your config/database.yml first")
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  gem "yard"
end

group :test do
  gem "rails-dom-testing"
  gem 'mocha', '>= 2.0.1'
  gem 'simplecov', '~> 0.21.2', :require => false
  gem "ffi", platforms: [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin]
  # For running system tests
  gem 'puma', (Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.7') ? '< 6.0.0' : '>= 0')
  gem 'capybara', (if Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.6')
                     '~> 3.35.3'
                   elsif Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.7')
                     '~> 3.36.0'
                   else
                     '~> 3.38.0'
                   end)
  gem "selenium-webdriver", "~> 3.142.7"
  gem 'webdrivers', '4.6.1', require: false
  # RuboCop
  gem 'rubocop', '~> 1.26.0'
  gem 'rubocop-performance', '~> 1.13.0'
  gem 'rubocop-rails', '~> 2.14.0'
end

local_gemfile = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "Gemfile.local")
if File.exist?(local_gemfile)
  eval_gemfile local_gemfile
end

# Load plugins' Gemfiles
Dir.glob File.expand_path("../plugins/*/{Gemfile,PluginGemfile}", __FILE__) do |file|
  eval_gemfile file
end
gem "rspec"```


А в ответ на какую команду получаете ошибку? bundle install прошёл без ошибок?

Ошибку получаю уже на веб-странице, когда открываю Redmine.
bundle install был с ошибками сначала, не хватало unix-пакетов. Установил их - bundle прошёл без ошибок.

Ни разу не работала с редмайном, поэтому уточняю - какой командой вы его запускаете? И находитесь ли в этом момент в той же директории, откуда запускали bundle install? По какой-то причине не подхватываются установленные гемы (если они действительно установились). Есть ли rake в выводах команд gem list и bundle exec gem list?

Через gem list отображается:
...
rake (13.2.1, 13.0.6)
...
Через bundle exec gem list тоже есть:
...
rake (13.2.1)
...
Я конфигурацию apache настроил: указал document root до приложения и переменную PassengerRuby до интерпретатора Ruby.
Passenger запущен, как я понял, т.к. на странице с ошибкой его лого сверху.
bundle install запускал в папке с проектом.

Само приложение вы как запускаете? rails server? или как-то по-другому?

Через apache. Установил для apache модуль для работы с Руби.

В общем, ошибка, скорее всего в конфигурации apache. Буду разбираться.

напиши gem install rake -v 13.2.1
bundle install работает немного криво. Бывает проблемы с тем, когда глобально установлены другие версии одного гема. Просто установи его отдельно, если не помогло. Удали его целиком(все версии).
